# Django REST Framework - Unit Test Error

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am currently writing a unit test for the following `get_can_edit` function in my serializer:

```
def get_can_edit(self, obj):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    return user == obj.admin
```

In my test, I call the function here:

```
def test_get_can_edit(self):
    self.request1 = RequestFactory().post('./fake_path')
    self.request1.user = SimpleLazyObject(self.user1)
    self.request1.query_params = {}
    self.serializer1 = ConferenceSerializer(context={'request': self.request1})
    self.canEdit1 = self.serializer1.get_can_edit(self.conference)
```

When I run the test, it fails the the error:  `'User' object is not callable`, and references the following line in the serializer `get_can_edit` function:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
```

However, when running in browser, the get_can_edit function performs correctly and has no problem with the 'User' objet being callable.

I originally assumed that there was a problem with the format of the fake data I was creating (I'm using [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/advanced/) to create the fake data). Using a debugger, I went into the get_can_edit function both by calling the test, and through the server by making a real request. In both cases, `request.user` and `obj.admin` were in the correct form, so I ruled out a data formatting error.

Next, I tried

```
User.objects.get(username=request.user)
```

in the debuggers. It worked for the real request in the server, and returned the same `'User' object is not callable` error for the fake request in the test. I did a quick stack overflow/google search for `object is not callable` errors in Django, but it looked like other cases were solved by making sure a model was imported correctly (mine is definitely imported correctly).

So at this point I know that there's a problem with my test case that does not exist with the real request, but I can't really figure out what it is, and I'm running out of ideas.

Full code:

[The serializer](https://github.com/TomHeatwole/osf-meetings/blob/feature/conference-tests/meetings/conferences/serializers.py)

[The test](https://github.com/TomHeatwole/osf-meetings/blob/feature/conference-tests/meetings/conferences/tests.py)

Thanks so much, let me know if there's an easier way to go about this.

UPDATE:
 So I went back in the two different debuggers and did `User.objects.all()`. The one in the server with the real request returned the correct list of users. The one in the test with the fake request just returned anonymoususer. Because I'm using factory_boy to create my fake users, django can't find it in `User.objects`.

I've been told not to make real requests in my unit tests, so creating an actual user is out of the question.

I also tried changing the `get_can_edit` function to not check `User.objects.`. `request.user` is a `SimpleLazyObject` containing the user. What I tried doing was `request.user.id` and comparing it to `obj.admin.id`, but apparently when you do pretty much anything to a `SimpleLazyObject`, it consults `User.objects` to get to the actual User associated with it, so it still had the same error `'User' object is not callable`.

So the bottom line is this: **I need to add a fake user to `User.objects` without making a real request**

Comment: You are using `app.models.User` and `django.contrib.auth.model.User`. Whats the reason for that? Can you also post the relevant models?

Comment: They're the same model... I'm not sure why they're imported differently (I'm not the only collaborator on these pages), but I just tried changing the way they're imported and am running into the same problem. 

Documentation on the User model is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved here: [Django REST Framework - Fake objects for unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795394/django-rest-framework-fake-objects-for-unit-tests)

Basically `factory_boy` factories needed to be set up differently. Where I defined my factories I had the following line:

```
class UserFactory(factory.Factory):
```

But apparently instead of `factory.Factory`, it was supposed to say `factory.DjangoModelFactory` like so:

```
class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
```

This was a little obnoxious since the `factory_boy` [documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) has an example on the first page with `factory.Factory` but later on tells you to use `DjangoModelFactory`. I guess that's what I deserve for not reading the documentation thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to create a base class in order to use it across all your tests. Also that class extend from `APIClient` DRF class, that supports HTTP methods and you don't need to create `Request`  objects manually.

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class BaseAPITestCase(APITestCase):
    """
    Base class to initialize the test cases
    """

    self.user = YourUserFactory.create_batch(1)
    self.user_client = self.get_client(user=self.user)
```

In your Test

```
class YourTestClass(BaseAPITestCase):

    def test_get_can_edit(self):
        response = self.user_client.post('./fake_path')
        # proccess your response
```