# Django REST Framework - Fake objects for unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm writing unit tests for my Django app. Currently I'm using [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to make fake objects for testing. This works fine for most of my tests, but I'm having the following problem: **My factory_boy objects aren't showing up in `{model}.objects`**. For example, I'm trying to test the following method in my serializer:

```
def get_can_edit(self, obj):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    user = request.user
    admin = SimpleLazyObject(obj.admin)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    return user == obj.admin
```

Going through it with a debugger, I've determined that request.user correctly has my fake user, but User.objects does not have my fake user.

I'm wondering if there's a simple alternative to factory_boy that will actually add my fake objects to `{model}.objects` or if I'm just using factory_boy incorrectly? Or maybe there's a whole different approach... who knows.

Here's the code:

[The serializer](https://github.com/TomHeatwole/osf-meetings/blob/feature/conference-tests/meetings/conferences/serializers.py)

[The test](https://github.com/TomHeatwole/osf-meetings/blob/feature/conference-tests/meetings/conferences/tests.py)

Comment: You might like this also: https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **inherit from [`DjangoModelFactory`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html#the-djangomodelfactory-subclass) instead of `Factory`** base class in your `UserFactory` for objects to be saved onto the database.

From [`factory_boy` docs:](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html#the-djangomodelfactory-subclass)

> All factories for a Django `Model` **should use the `DjangoModelFactory`**
>   base class.

```
class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory): # use DjangoModelFactory base class

    class Meta: 
        model = models.User
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That did it.